# Using GridLayout - how to set JPanel size?

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, grid-layout

[image]I'm using `GridLayout` and all my panels have the same size, how can I change their size?

I tried all functions getPreferred/Minimum/MaximumSize which makes that, and nothing.
I still want to stay with GridLayout
Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you trying to make the sizes of your GridLayout-held components different from each other? GridLayout does not allow this. Please clarify your question. Please show code and/or images.

Comment: `GridLayout` is not the best choice, but also remember, a component provides sizing hints to the layout manager API via `getPreferred/Minimum/MaximumSize`

Comment: look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4699892/how-to-set-the-component-size-with-gridlayout-is-there-a-better-way)

Comment: @Dando18: I recognize that link -- that's my answer. :)

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Meant for OP to see. Like the name by the way.

Comment: Try putting another Panel with a different layout within the bottom cells and put the button in that panel;

Comment: I'd use a GridBagLayout for most but not all of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I managed to split all the part above to my first JPanel which located to NORTH. 
Then, the JPanel with the button I did the same to be located SOUTH. 
So the scrolled JLabel in now located in the CENTER which allows him to be flexible.

```
    JPanel mainPanel1 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(6,1));
    mainPanel1.add(titleLabel);
    mainPanel1.add(participantPanel);
    mainPanel1.add(swimPanel);
    mainPanel1.add(ridePanel);
    mainPanel1.add(runPanel);
    mainPanel1.add(categoriesPanel);

    JPanel mainPanel2 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,1));        
    mainPanel2.add(listPanel);

    JPanel mainPanel3 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,1));
    mainPanel3.add(buttonsPanel);

    this.getContentPane().add(mainPanel1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    this.getContentPane().add(mainPanel2, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    this.getContentPane().add(mainPanel3, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

Answer (score 6):

By its very nature, all components held by a GridLayout will have the same size. If you want them to be different sizes,

1. You can use a different layout, such as a GridBagLayout or MigLayout or
2. Use the GridLayout to hold same-sized JPanels that act as containers for other components. The inner components of course can be different sizes. For example: a chess board that holds its chess cells in a GridLayout, but that allows each cell to hold a chess piece that has varying sizes.

If this doesn't answer your question, then please clarify your question.

Comment: @RoeyGolzarpoor This answer still applies. All the cells will be the same size unless you use multiple layers of layout managers and then you can resize the components within the cells